# remove duplicated words in map with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
{this.state.filterDataRows && this.state.filterDataRows.map((row, index) => {
    return row.cells.filter( val => {
            if(val.text.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.columnFilter.toLowerCase())){
                return true
            }
                return false
            }
        ).map((cell) => {
            if (this.camelToColNames(cell.originalDBColumn) === this.camelToColNames(Object.keys(fd)[0])) {
                if (cell.text !== "" && cell.text !== "-") {
                    return (<MenuItem
                        key={index}
                        value={row.cells.filter((cell1) => {
                            return ((this.camelToColNames(cell1.originalDBColumn) === this.camelToColNames(Object.keys(fd)[0])) ?
                            cell1.text : "");
                        })}>
                        {cell.text }
                        {console.log("cell.text---------",cell.text)}
                        </MenuItem >)
                }
            }
        })
    }
)}
```

This is the code I developed with react js project. Its **output** is:

```
cell.text--------- 30.9
cell.text--------- 30.9
cell.text--------- 30.9
cell.text--------- 30.9
cell.text--------- 11.9
cell.text--------- 11.9
```

I have coming **cell.text** one by one. Now I trying to validate duplicate text.

**What would be the best possible options?**

Answer (score 0):

You can filter directly while rendering but it could cause some performance issues if filterDataRows contains large amount of data:

```
{this.state.filterDataRows 
&& this.state.filterDataRows
   .map((row, index) => {
                            
                            return row.cells.filter( val => {
                              if(val.text.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.columnFilter.toLowerCase())){
                                return true
                              }
                              return false
                            }
                          )
                          .filter(({text}, index)=>row.cells.findIndex(({text:t})=>t===text)===index)
                          .map((cell) => {
                              if (this.camelToColNames(cell.originalDBColumn) === this.camelToColNames(Object.keys(fd)[0])) {
                                if (cell.text !== "" && cell.text !== "-") {
                                  return (<MenuItem
                                    key={index}
                                    value={row.cells.filter((cell1) => {
                                      return ((this.camelToColNames(cell1.originalDBColumn) === this.camelToColNames(Object.keys(fd)[0])) ?
                                        cell1.text : "");
                                    })}>
                                    {cell.text }
                                    {console.log("cell.text---------",cell.text)}
                                  </MenuItem >)
                                }
                              }
                            })
                          }
                          )}
```

Comment: Hi Ossama Ismaili,
Can you please explain how I apply this to my source code? which line?
I can share my code with you,
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Yyf7zXmYdqwhKFtkyyoSfw9TSbOZO9wj0Xc4fZ9qqxw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi, well I updated the answer, I was confused between filterDataRows and row.cells

Comment: Please if you find the answer useful can you click the up button so more people can reach this answer if they find a similar issue.

Comment: Hi Ossama, I applied it but it was not working. I shared you my original file and important things. please look into this. https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/17ujZdGhAYsFWcGDbNYwtd6oPVdUPZyiW

Comment: I tried .but did not have a good result..can you please apply your changes to this original code? 

https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/17ujZdGhAYsFWcGDbNYwtd6oPVdUPZyiW